# PS server of distributed tensorflow use all GPUs automatically?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I was studying Distributed Tensorflow.https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed

```
# Create and start a server for the local task.
server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
       job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
       task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
```

When I start only one ps server. I saw it used all GPUs and all GPUs memory.

(My env : 2 Tesla K80 GPUs)

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                            GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name    Usage      |
|==================================================|
|    0     22854    C   python            10891MiB |
|    1     22854    C   python            10890MiB |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

According to  https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu , I reduce the memory usage.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
   job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
   task_index=FLAGS.task_index,
   config=config)
```

But I hope PS server only use one GPU, how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python train.py
This can also be helpful if you are running from the command line to restrict usage only to gpu id 0. you can specify multiple ids like CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2,3 for workers also.

Answer (score 0):

`config.gpu_options.visible_device_list` is the way to specify which GPUs are visible to tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks,@Alexandre Passos 
Yes, but there are two parts in distributed tensorflow. The PS server and the  worker . I just hope only worker to use all GPUs not ps server.

Comment: I think you might have better luck starting a non-gpu TensorFlow build on the parameter server; then no GPUs will be used there (GPUs in the parameter server are often not necessary).